# How to build with a custom eglfs cursor atlas?

Tags: qt5, embedded-linux

I'm trying to change the eglfs mouse cursor graphics for my embedded linux QT application (QT5.5).  I have the new cursor atlas PNG and the new JSON descriptor file, but the documentation is rather vague:

".. a custom cursor atlas can be provided by setting the QT_QPA_EGLFS_CURSOR environment variable to the name of a JSON file. The file can also be embedded into the application via Qt's resource system."

I'd prefer to keep everything within the resource system if possible but I can't work out how to do it.. do I need a specific qrc file containing the path to the JSON file?  I assume that the PNG file would also need to be added as a resource so that it gets built into the application?

If adding it via the resource system is a bad idea where's the correct place to set the QT_QPA_EGLFS_CURSOR environment variable?  I'm currently specifying the platform on the command line via "-platform eglfs"; will this be ok or will I need to set the platform to eglfs in the build?

Answer (score 1):

After much trial, error and digging around I have found the solution that I was looking for within the resource system.

Create a new resource file called "cursor.qrc", the contents of which needs to be two lines:

```
path/to/your/custom-cursor-atlas.png
cursor.json
```

The first line (path to your cursor atlas) must be relative to your resource directory.

You then need to put the JSON file (contents as described in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/embedded-linux.html)) in the root of your resource directory.  It must be called "*cursor.json*", and its image location line must must match the location in your new resource file and be of the format:

```
"image": ":/path/to/your/custom-cursor-atlas.png",
```

This will then include your cursor atlas in resources, and Qt will find it when your application starts.

Answer (score 0):

Run time solution example:

```
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=~
export QT_QPA_EGLFS_CURSOR=~/cursor.json
```

In the `cursor.json`:

```
"image": "cursor.png",
```

Put your custom `cursor.png` atlas into your home dir (`~`) then run the Qt app from there.